# Trig Identities Problem

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to find the trig identity of this problem:

$\sin(x)\cos(x)\tan(x)\sec(x)\csc(x)$

I already know the answer is $\tan(x)$, but everytime I've tried to solve it I always ended up changing it.

Comment: $\sin x$ and $\csc x$ cancel, as do $\cos x$ and $\sec x$.

Comment: http://www.sosmath.com/trig/Trig5/trig5/trig5.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sin(x)\cos(x)\tan(x)\sec(x)\csc(x)=\sin(x)\csc(x)\sec(x)\cos(x)\tan(x)\\
=1\cdot1\cdot\tan(x)=\tan(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

This problem is actually pretty easy to solve.
$$\sin(x)\cos(x)\tan(x)\csc(x)\sec(x)$$
$$=\sin(x)\cos(x)\tan(x)\times\dfrac{1}{\sin(x)}\times\dfrac{1}{cos(x)}$$
Now you can cancel out the terms
$$1\times 1\times \tan(x)$$
$$=tan(x)$$
That is how you get $\sin(x)\cos(x)\tan(x)\csc(x)\sec(x)=\tan(x)$

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple.
$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
\sin x\cos x\tan x\sec x\csc x&=\cancel{\sin x}\cancel{\cos x}\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\frac{1}{\cancel{\cos x}}\frac{1}{\cancel{\sin x}}\\
&=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\\
&=\tan x
\end{align}
$$